# Information theory from a (very pure) mathematician's perspective

Tags: information-theory

I'm a pure mathematician interested in learning about information theory. Unfortunately, I'm about as pure as they come - my specialty is mathematical logic, and I have absolutely no experience with programming or anything of a computational nature. I tried looking at Shannon's original paper, but the profusion of numbers intimidated me (I'm a mathematician after all!) When he starts discussing the particulars of coding specific alphabets, my brain begins to asking whether this attention to detail is really necessary and soon zones out... It took Church's thesis for granted some time ago. (Pathetic, I know.)

I'm wondering if there's some introduction to information theory written with people like me in mind. Something which uses the language of measure theory and recursion theory, and works in the greatest generality. Perhaps an expert in the area has written some notes in this direction as an idle folly?

I realize that this might not be the place to ask this question, and apologize if this is the case.

Comment: There is a good reference that completely describes entropy from the combinatorial point-of-view with respect to maximizing the log-likelihood of multinomial distributions. I need to find it...

Comment: You can look at the classic text of Cover and Thomas. Not exactly what you're looking for, but a very readable account.

Comment: [Here](http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0512017) is the reference as I mentioned earlier.

Comment: Sometimes very pure mathematicians need to get their hands dirty. It helps them develop their immune systema. Out of curiosity, what kind of logician has "no experience with anything of a computational nature"? Isn't computability theory "of a computational nature"?

Comment: Let's not forget that computability theory is really the study of everything which is *not* computable! Thanks @nmancuso1, that looks very promising.

Comment: You might consider approaching Information Theory via Kolmogorov Complexity. It's a more general field, more concerned with a platonic world of Turing Machines and such, and less with singular practical applications. Information Theory then follows as a kind of special case of Kolmogorov Complexity. It certainly uses the languages of recursion theory and measure theory.

Comment: If you want a pure mathematician's viewpoint, why is this question not on [math.SE]?

Comment: I call troll on this one.  This paper contains no more numbers than do any other "pure mathematics" paper.  It has something like two examples which involves number which hardly should be intimidating.  And alphabets is an extremely natural abstraction of sets of natural numbers that are used in recursion theory.  Is it possible to ask you what background you really have?  Because a little mathematical maturity is all that's needed to read Shannon's paper.

Comment: recently was looking into many refs on coding theory which has advanced very substantially since shannon.... shannon is a great but very old ref... but will hold off on posting anything until user6618 clarifies

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the topic of "**Algorithmic Information Theory**" (AIT). 
This area is the collision of information theory and computer science. For example "[Information and Randomness: An Algorithmic Perspective](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540434666)" written by [cristian calude](http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~cristian/) contains interesting subjects in this area. You can find more in the [AIT](http://www.hutter1.net/ait.htm) website.

Comment: Please add more information than just a link. See [here](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for a guideline as to what constitutes a good answer on this platform.